# Multi database y Multi sitios Django

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework

Intento hacer una Aplicación API Rest en Django y lo que intento hacer que varios dominios(example1.com, example2.com, example3.com) al momento de hacer peticiones sean dirigidos con la base de datos de cada cual.

Cada dominio tiene su base de datos en postgresql.

Django permite utilizar Multi Databases y para poder utilizar esa estrategia hay 2 maneras:

1.- Al momento de hacer una consulta en el ORM

```
 Articulos.object.using('database1').get(id=id) #por ejemplo
```

2.-  Crear un archivo llamado routers.py, donde se define una clase sobreescribiendo algunos metodos

```
class DatabaseRouter(object):
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    request = HttpRequest()
    if request.META.get('HTTP_HOST) == 'domain1':
        return 'database1'
    if request.META.get('HTTP_HOST) == 'domain2':
        return 'database2'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    request = HttpRequest()
    if request.META.get('HTTP_HOST) == 'domain1':
        return 'database1'
    if request.META.get('HTTP_HOST) == 'domain2':
        return 'database2'
    return None

def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):

    if db == 'database1' or db == 'database2':
        return model._meta.app_label == 'app'
    elif model._meta.app_label == 'app':
        return False

    return None
```

se integra esa clase al Settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['APIapp.routers.DatabaseRouter',]
```

Hasta aqui va bien la información.

Ahora, la pregunta es ¿ Como puedo hacer para que al momento de ingresar el dominio, routers.py sepa que dominio y por ende que database elegir?

Segun lo que yo he leido, hacerlo a través de un middleware pero no he podido, entonces se me ocurre recuperar el en routers.py el dominio. Las vistas de Django contienen un argumento **request** donde incluye el hostname, pero no he podido recuperar ese objecto de Django y mandarselo a routers.py

¿Que es lo que puedo hacer ?

Answer (score 1):

Pues si, la mejor manera era a través de un middleware
y ahora routers.py quedo asi:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import Http404
import threading
request_cfg = threading.local()

class RouterDBMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_view( self, request, view_func, args, kwargs ):
        for db_name in settings.DATABASE_CURSORS:
            if db_name in request.get_host():
                request_cfg.db = db_name
        if not request_cfg:
            request_cfg.db = 'default'

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if hasattr(request_cfg, 'db'):
            del request_cfg.db
        return response

class DatabaseRouter(object):
    def _default_db( self ):
        if hasattr( request_cfg, 'db' ):
            return request_cfg.db
        else:
            return 'default'

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return self._default_db()
    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return self._default_db()
    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == request_cfg.db:
            return model._meta.app_label == 'APIapp'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'APIapp':
            return False
        return None
```

En settings.py declare una lista con los valores de las bases de datos para llamarla

```
DATABASE_CURSORS = ['interprice','prueba1','prueba2']
```

El middleware

```
'APIapp.routers.RouterDBMiddleware',
```

y el router

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['APIapp.routers.DatabaseRouter',]
```

y funciono !!!

Comparto las ligas de donde me base:

http://django-book.blogspot.mx/2012/06/capitulo-3-los-principios-de-las.html

http://django-book.blogspot.mx/2012/06/middleware.html

https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2037/

https://gist.github.com/gijzelaerr/7a3130c494215a0dd9b2